# Vectorising max distance function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

Really quick questions,

I have the following function for distance

```
def distance(a1,a2,b1,b2):
     return sqrt((a2-a1)**2 + (b2-b1)**2)
```

I want to calculate distances between each point in column A in my dataframe and column B and save maximum in column C.

For now I iterate through each, in a nested loop and use distance(df.loc[i, colA], dftest.loc[i,colB], dftest.loc[j,colA], dftest.loc[j.colB]) and check if greater than previous.
I know there is a way to vectorise it, just can't get my head around it.

I don't need any ready function, but clear way how to vectorise it please.

I appreciate any help!

EDIT:
Example of the dataframe, with colB being desired output:

```
ColA| ColB| ColC
7.6 |8.2  |6.79 (max distance which is between this row and row3)
6.6 |4.4  |3.92 (max distance is with row1, greater than row3)
4.4 |2.2  |6.79 (max distance is with row1)
```

So eg ColC in first row is calculated with distance(7.6,8.2,4.4,2.2) but function distnace has to go thorugh all combinations

With larger dfs that gets really expensive

Comment: So your `columnA` has 2 coordinates in each cell?

Comment: please provide an example of your dataframe

Comment: @QuangHoang no, those are 2 columns with regular floats. The way it works now, for df.iloc[0, columnA] it iterates through whole column B and saves the max, then goes to df.iloc[1,columnA] and repeats. This has O(n^2) now

Comment: @mozway ColA and ColB have float numbers, colC would be maxdistance. Rows depend on the dataset

Comment: can you still provide a small example? 3/4 rows and the expected output?

Comment: Use [distance_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance_matrix.html)...

Comment: I am looking for clean vectorised solution if you can help me please

Comment: @QuangHoang thank you but as mentioned I am not looking for ready function, but clean implementation since this is for school assingment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want to use libraries, you can use the underlying numpy array, broadcast the vectorial computation and get the max:

```
import numpy as np
a = df.values  # easier reference to numpy array
b = (a[:,0]-a[:,0,None])**2+(a[:,1]-a[:,1,None])**2  # (a2-a1)**2 + (b2-b1)**2
df['ColC'] = np.sqrt(b.max(0))
```

output:

```
   ColA  ColB      ColC
0   7.6   8.2  6.800000
1   6.6   4.4  3.929377
2   4.4   2.2  6.800000
```

Comment: that is amazing solution, thank you very much! I'm trying break down your code now and get my head around how you sliced it, really helpful

Comment: This is quite simple in fact, the key part is the broadcasting using `[…, None]` that adds an extra dimension to be able to compare all combinations of rows.